# The online job application doesn't explicitly ask for my complete work history, do I need to list all jobs?

Tags: job-search, applications

I am working on an online job application where the employment history section doesn't say whether I need to list my complete work history. I have had several short-term part-time jobs (2-3 month long, for example) while I was in school, and they are not pertinent to the job I am currently applying to. I wonder if it is necessary to list them.

EDIT: I am actually asking about the online application form, not my resume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, just change the headline from Past Employments to Relevant experience or something similar. This is especially important if the jobs were a long time ago (judging from your question it was probably not that far away in time?).

I sometimes get applications that list work as mailman 20 years ago for a programming job. It just takes up space and is wasted time for me when going through resumes.

If leaving a job out of your resume would leave a big gap, leave it in but just use one line for it.

Comment: Thanks Andreas. I am actually asking about the online application form, not my resume. Does that make a difference?

Comment: Hi, what is the title of the field that you are filling in? If it's "All previous job experience", they want all of it. If it's "Relevant job experience", leave out the non-relevant.

Comment: The employment section of the application form doesn't say whether it wants all previous job experience or relevant job experience. I am applying for a data analyst job in a research lab at a university. These 2-3 month part-time jobs were jobs I had when I was in grad school, so I am not too concerned about gaps.

Comment: If it's part time, short each time and doesn't leave any gaps - the only other question if it in any way adds  to your potential job as a data analyst. Will anything you learned during your short part time jobs help you in any way? If so, include and mention briefly why you think it will help you.

Answer (score 2):

**No**.  If the jobs are not relevant and do not leave any strange gaps, feel free to omit them.  Or better yet, summarize them into a bullet point:

> 20xx-20xy: Part-time service industry jobs while studying at
>   university, details on request.