# Can I recover from quitting a horrible first job after a month and a half?

Tags: quitting, first-job

Due to extreme pressure from my parents, I foolishly accepted the first job I was offered, even though it has nothing to do with my strengths or interests.

I might have stuck with it for a while for the sake of my resume, but my boss is ridiculously harsh, and constantly degrades me.

The whole startup is (surprise) horribly unorganized. On my first day, they literally sat me at a desk, explained my task in 5 minutes then set me to work. No tour of the office. No introductions. No training.

I feel like I need to quit, especially as I don't feel that my boss may very well fire me soon anyway.

I'd like to apply to new jobs, but ***should I list this position on my resume?***

Comment: Welcome to the site cloudboy37. Have look at this question for some useful information and check the links in the comment I posted on it: [Omitted short-term job from job application and worried about background check](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/54463/omitted-short-term-job-from-job-application-and-worried-about-background-check?lq=1) (not a duplicate)

Comment: Despite the rabid unpopularity of my answer, I'd like your title to say something more specific than "recover." I'm not sure if you expect to become broke and destitute if this goes wrong or if you're merely concerned the next place you apply might just reject you.

Comment: I also encourage you to read literally every other question on this exact same topic you can find in the sidebar to your right -->. I personally felt your gripes were suspiciously, surprisingly menial and this indicated you didn't understand what a job is like and someone should point that out, but if we're [*not* okay with pointing that out](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), then I really don't understand why your situation is different from the dozens of others already documented. Not sure which to close as duplicate, I'll pick one and flag it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can one resign from a new job gracefully?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/7149/how-can-one-resign-from-a-new-job-gracefully)

Comment: To be more specific re. title, besides the vague wording, the other problem is that the question in the title is not the question in the question. Perhaps I should have focused more on the "resume" issue in the first place and flagged as duplicate right away. Good luck!

Comment: How well do you know which of your strengths and interests would get you another job? How much money does the job have to make to support your standard of living? What kind of work conditions do you know as perhaps 99.999% of jobs would be horrible in your eyes but completely legal to run the way they do.

Comment: I think it also depends on what kind of job this is, and what kind of training you have. If you've graduated, say, computer science or math, and you want to work as a software developer, and you ended up in a startup as a _developer_ role where you need to do Ruby as full stack, that might be hard and not what you want. In that case, find a corporation with lots of structure and apply for a _junior Java developer_ role or an internshop as a developer. But if you come from school and you got, say, an accounting job but you'd prefer being a chef, that's a different kind of thing. Please clarify.

Comment: It sounds like you're in a poorly run (high stress for everyone, including the boss) startup.  In your next position, look for a company that's been in business for 10 years or more.

Answer (score 8):

The lone advice I know in that case of situation is : "look elsewhere".

Especially as you didn't already change job a lot of times. That you made a mistake once, most prospective employers are going to understand.

If you had your 4th job in 7 months, it would be different. There, nope. But the important things are :

1. Be sure to have your arguments ready for the question "why do you leave them so early?", as the underlying question is "will that candidate leave as soon as recruited?", and that's this second question you shall prepare to answer, even if asked the first.
2. Note the experience on your resume only if relevant to jour job hunt. 45 days testing software if you're looking for an accounting place is not relevant.
3. Don't expect miracles. Workplace is not paradise. People have a lot to do, and won't be as nice to you as you'd expect. Might be better than what you have, but you're not gonna be the center of the world.
4. Be positive. People prefer working with positive people. When interviewed, say "They are very nice, but really, it's just not the kind of things I want to do. I'm so sad I made a mistake by going there, I know I won't have a third chance. I'd Loooove to do what you do."

**TL;DR** : Be positive, look for the next step, and Be ready to laugh when remembering your first experience.

Answer (score 7):

You can start looking, but stick it out until you find something.  You will have to be very picky to find something better and that means staying employed until you do so that you don't have to take the next bad job that comes along. Trust me there are much worse jobs than what you describe. No sense in going from the frying pan into the fire.

It is however pretty typical to not be given training or even much direction and be expected to perform. In my first job I was told to just do whatever my predecessor had done and that I could figure it out from the files she left. Unfortunately, she had not left any. And while I don't care for bosses that yell, there are a lot of them, so you want to take your time to find the right situation.

You can put it on the resume. People expect there to be some blips in the first jobs until you find what you want. The key is to make sure that you can tell them what you are looking for and to tell them that you made a mistake in selecting this job and why it didn't suit you without badmouthing the employer. That can be tricky I know, but it is a skill that is useful to have for the rest of your career.